# rgbdslam error: gsl/gsl_linalg.h not found

Tags: slam, navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

when i run the command   roslaunch rgbdslam rgbdslam.launch
it shows the error:

ERROR: cannot launch node of type [rgbdslam/rgbdslam]: Cannot locate node of type [rgbdslam] in package [rgbdslam]

And when run the command "rosmake --rosdep-install rgbdslam" ,showing the error:

In file included from /home/lihaiyang/ros/rgbdslam/external/gicp/bfgs_funcs.cpp:37:0:
/home/lihaiyang/ros/rgbdslam/external/gicp/optimize.h:44:28: fatal error： gsl/gsl_linalg.h：not have the file or directory
Compiler interrupt
make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/gicp.dir/external/gicp/bfgs_funcs.o] error 1
make[3]:leaving the directory `/home/lihaiyang/ros/rgbdslam/build' make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/gicp.dir/all] error 2 make[2]:leaving the directory` /home/lihaiyang/ros/rgbdslam/build'
make[1]: *** [all] error 2
make[1]:leaving the directory `/home/lihaiyang/ros/rgbdslam/build'
Thank you very much!!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32662/rgbdslam-error:-gsl/gsl_linalg.h-not-found/) by [Ocean](https://answers.ros.org/users/2058/ocean/) on ROS Answers with karma: 66 on 2012-04-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Steven Bellens](https://answers.ros.org/users/55/steven-bellens/) on 2012-04-25**:
Please specify ROS version and platform details. The gsl_linalg.h header is included in the gsl-dev package

**Comment by [Ocean](https://answers.ros.org/users/2058/ocean/) on 2012-05-07**:
ROS version is electric,Linux for Ubuntu11.10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

http://answers.ros.org/question/12911/rgdbslam-installation-missing-gslgsl_linalgh

---

Originally posted by [Ocean](https://answers.ros.org/users/2058/ocean/) with karma: 66 on 2012-04-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ocean](https://answers.ros.org/users/2058/ocean/) on 2012-05-23**:
sudo apt-get install libgsl0-dev